# Language not supported in Active Reports

Tags: asp.net, fonts, activereports

I am trying to display **Lao** language in **Active Reports 9** with font "Dejavu San condensed".

It is working correctly in local environment, BUT in deployed environment the textbox is blank.

Can anyone help me please.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that required font is installed in the deployed environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Yes , as you said it is not installed in deployed environment . I will install it and check once .